# How do I add a custom actions dropdown for my custom VBA Script

Tags: vba, outlook, menu

I am trying to add a custom actions button for my custom VBA Script similar to how we have options underneath almost every button press in Outlook/Excel/Word etc. Is there a way I could achieve this? Please refer to the picture.

[image: Extra Options]

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a custom menu item. I can't say I have tried this myself, but I think this is what you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg508923(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: How do you do it for outlook? Same manner? Workbook_Open() can be replaced by?

Comment: As I wrote on my post, I have not tried this myself.  I am assuming that this could be applied to any office product. But I could be mistaken.  You just have to try it.  Try it first in Excel to verify that it works, then try it in Outlook.

Comment: At least now you are closer to an answer.  Figure out if one of the functions written for VB is unique for Excel

Comment: They aren't unfortunately. Outlook 2013 doesn't use those functions anymore. It uses Fluent UI which I'll have to dig into.

Comment: I wasn't able to give you an answer, but at least I was able to point you in the right direction; which is almost as good.  Glad I could be of some help.